# Does currency in an aircraft requiring a type rating provide currency for same category and class?

Tags: currency

If a pilot has basic currency to carry passengers in an aircraft requiring a type rating, say a Boeing 737, does that mean the pilot is also current in an aircraft in the same category and class (AMEL) that does not require a type rating, e.g. Diamond DA42?

[61.57](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.57) has the caveat "If a type rating is required". So the question is whether that caveat means that the type is not relevant for considering currency in the DA42. Which would suggest that for the DA42 currency you need only consider flights in the same category and class so any flights in an AMEL (regardless of type) would count.

Comment: I believe that is correct, but insurance companies may have other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, based on your question and example, if a pilot is FAR 61.57 current in a B737 (which requires a type rating), the pilot is also current to carry passengers in a DA42 (which does not require a type rating), but is the same ***category*** and ***class*** (of airplane).

[14 CFR part 61.57 (a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.57(a)) states:

> (a) General experience.

> > (1) Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft carrying passengers or of an aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember unless that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days, and -
>
> > > (i) The person acted as the sole manipulator of the flight controls; and
>
> > > (ii) **The required takeoffs and landings were performed in an aircraft of the same category, class, and type (if a type rating is required)**, and, if the aircraft to be flown is an airplane with a tailwheel, the takeoffs and landings must have been made to a full stop in an airplane with a tailwheel.

*(emphasis is mine)*